# How to make a Div with many div childs, having one child covering whole parent's space

Tags: html, css

I want to create a css class that will make a specific child to expand to fit the whole space of its parent, while others children without this class, should stay smaller and be visible in front of the biggest one. When the user click on any children, I will add this class and remove from others, so the clicked one will have the same behavior.

Please, see the attached images to understand the question

- The black one is the parent
- Blue, pink, green and red are children
- I clicked in blue and it became focused

[image: How it is now]

[image: What I want achieve]

How can I do it with css?

Comment: At first image blue child is bigger than others but it was my mistake, all them have same width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get this behavior by setting this style to focused children:

```
background-color: blue;
height: 100% !important;
width: 100% !important;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
z-index:9998;
```

and this style for unfocused ones:

```
...
background-color: pink;
z-index: 9999; /* higher to be in front of focused one */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put an "active" class on each children (after you click it) with the following css:

```css
.parent{
  background: #999;
  border: 5px solid black;
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  position:relative;
}
.box {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        position: relative;
        animation-name: raw;  
        animation-duration: 2s;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;         
}
.box.active{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.red{
  background: red;
}
.blue{
  background: blue;
}
.green{
  background: green;
}
.pink {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
 <div class="parent">
   <div class="box active blue"></div>
   <div class="box red"></div>
   <div class="box green"></div>
   <div class="box pink"></div>
  </div>
```

Basically you make the desired child absolutely positioned and stretch it to its parent size. If you try adding the active class on the other box divs you will see